# Passing a JSON string to django using JQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm a bit new to Django and trying to understand it. Currently, I'm creating a network topology visualiser (think routers and switches connected together). It works fine and all of the data is saved in a javascript object.

I want to have the ability to, when a user clicks a button, send this javascript object to django so that it can be parsed and handled appropriately. I did a lot of research and found a bunch of similar implementation which use a combination of JQuery and ajax to POST a JSON string. This is some of my code currently:

mainapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^NetworkTopology/', include('OpenAutomation.NetworkTopology.urls')),
    url(r'^NetworkTopology/json/', include('OpenAutomation.NetworkTopology.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

NetworkTopology/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^json/$', views.returnjson, name='returnjson'),
]
```

NetworkTopology/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')


def returnjson(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        request_data = request.POST
        print("Raw Data: " + request_data.body)
        return HttpResponse("OK")
```

JavaScript function (return JSON button is pressed):

```
function returnJsonTop(){
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/NetworkTopology/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(nodes.get(),null,4),
                    success: function (data) {
                         //this gets called when server returns an OK response
                         alert("it worked!");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                         alert("it didnt work");
                    }
                });
            });           
        }
```

In my index template, I have created a button which calls the returnJsonTop() function when it is pressed:

```
<button id="submitJson" onclick="returnJsonTop();">Deploy</button>
```

Currently, when I press the Deploy button, I just get the 'it didn't work' alert that has been setup to handle an errors. I'd really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction here. I suspect the issue is in my urls.py files but I've tried various combinations of urls without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those reading this later, this is what I did:

mainapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^NetworkTopology/', include('OpenAutomation.NetworkTopology.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

NetworkTopology/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^json/$', views.returnjson, name='returnjson'),
]
```

NetworkTopology/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')


@csrf_exempt
def returnjson(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        request_data = request.POST
        print("Raw Data: " + str(request_data))
        return HttpResponse("OK")
```

I was getting a 403 error so I added '@csrf_exempt'. I'll probably change this to handle it properly afterwards.

Return JSON function:

```
function returnJsonTop(){
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/NetworkTopology/json/',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(nodes.get(),null,4)
            });         
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access `body` on `request.POST`. But body is an attribute directly of the request. Your code should be:

```
    request_data = request.body
    print("Raw Data: " + request_data)
```

Also note, in your Javascript that `$(document).ready` line makes no sense there; you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you dont even need to use all this in your ajax call

```
  data: JSON.stringify(nodes.get(),null,4),
```

replace by

```
  data: nodes.get(),
```

should be enough as long as this method returns a valid json object

Second  one, I ´d strongly recommend you to use a framework to help you to parse JSON

Python have may, but to illustrate this example, I've used django rest framework, which is a very good one.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
import json
import controllers#this class belongs to my business logic layer, you can encapsulate yours and use instead of it

#in this solution you must create a pre-parser to handle responses
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

@csrf_exempt # this is for prevent invasions
def login(request):
#this one here handle your jquery post data into a valid json object in python represented by a Dict
    envelopin = json.loads(request.body)
# here we pass the dict inside my business controll logic routine which also responds with a valid Python Dict
    envelopout = controllers.login(envelopin)
# and for last, we use our pre-parser Class to make your response be handled by jquery as valid json
    return JSONResponse(envelopout)
```

and that is it, you success jQuery data variable, will hold the envelopout json object, in the same shape as it has inside yor django-python code.

hope this help